# implemented javascript button by laravel, but no response(no error)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to delete the registered comment, but don't working.
Registering comments using form was success, but removing comments using javascript does not work well.
When I click 'DELECT COMMENT' on the screen, it does not work, there is no error. There is no response.
"dd ('test');" in the Controller also does not work, so it seems to be a problem before the controller runs.
There are my code.

*comment.blade.php

```
<div class="action__comment">
@can('destroy', $comment)
    <button type="submit" class="btn__delete__comment">{{ trans('DELECT COMMENT') }}</button> •
@endcan
</div>
```

*web.php

```
Route::resource('comments','CommentsController',['only' => ['destroy','update']]);
Route::resource('articles.comments','CommentsController',['only' => 'store']);
```

*php artisan route:list

```
[root@test laravel]# php artisan route:list
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so' - libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                         | Name                    | Action                                              | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                           |                         | App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController@index        | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                    |                         | Closure                                             | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | articles/{article}/comments | articles.comments.store | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store       | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE    | comments/{comment}          | comments.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy     | web,auth     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | comments/{comment}          | comments.update         | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@update      | web,auth     |
```

*CommentsController.php

```
public function destroy(\App\Comment $comment)
{
    //dd('test'); <- don't work
    $comment->delete();
    flash()->success(trans('forum.deleted'));
    return back();
}
```

*index.blade.php

```
@section('script')
@parent
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$('.btn__delete__comment').on('click', function(e) {
    var commentId = $(this).closest('.item__comment').data('id'),
    articleId = $('#item__article').data('id');

    if (confirm('{{ trans('forum.comments.deleting') }}')) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/comments/" + commentId,
        data: {
            _method: "DELETE"
        }
    }).then(function() {
        $('#comment_'+commentId).fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});
    });
    }
});
</script>
@stop
```

What is problem?
Please your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first, in case of a http request of ajax, you can confirm the response as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/comments/" + commentId,
    data: {
        _method: "DELETE"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
       console.log(data.responseText); //Here!
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#comment_'+commentId).fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```

and, when I tried your code, I got the following message.

`No query results for model [App\Comment].`

so, I fixed your code of `Controller` as follows, then it worked.

```
class CommentsController extends AppController
{
    public function destroy($id)
    {
            //dd('test'); <- don't work
            $comment = \App\Comment::find($id);
            $comment->delete();
            #flash()->success(trans('forum.deleted'));
            return back();
    }
}
```

I hope it will go well.

**EDIT**

Sorry, maybe you are using `Route Model Binding`, so your Controller code doesn't seem to have a problem.

I think, using javascript code above, you might get some hints.

```
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
       console.log(data.responseText); //Here!
    }
```

Could you try?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I'm sorry, but your code also didn't working. I clicked 'DELECT COMMENT', no response...

Comment: Is `javascript` outputting any error? Could you check `console` on your browser?

Comment: I clicked delete button, but console is empty.